# Putting a Calendar in a customized vertical tab setting. C# - Winform

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, tabcontrol, monthcalendar

Hello so I have a customized vertical tab using the drawitem. However I can't put something in the tab control strip. I want to put a calender there so that I can utilize the free space however the tab-control doesn't let me do that. Is there a possible way of doing that thing?

*here's the image attached
[image: 1]

**I want it to look like this but in a vertical format so that I can utilize the empty space in photo 1
[image: 2]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *simplest* way is to *not* add it to the Tab Control.  Just add the control to the form, but make sure it sits on *top* of the Tab Control:

Simple example:

```
MonthCalendar mc1 = new MonthCalendar();
this.Controls.Add(mc1);
mc1.Location = new Point(0, this.ClientSize.Height - mc1.Height);
mc1.Anchor = AnchorStyles.Left | AnchorStyles.Bottom;
mc1.BringToFront();
```

Comment: How can I edit its location sir? because it pops in the lower left portion of my form.

Comment: @rjtubera Load or in the constructor.  You can use the Designer, too.  Just add the control to an empty spot on the form, then move it into your location above the tab control (using arrow keys or enter the location manually).  You have to obviously avoid having the control getting sucked into any container controls like the Tab control.

Comment: and sir is there a tutorial regarding with this? because I want to add label that overlaps the tab-control. I really want to learn on how to do this because it gives me a lot of problem. T_T

Comment: Wew! I never thought it would work! I spent several hours searching for this and I never thought that the solution was pretty easy! THANK YOU VERY MUCH MISTER!

Comment: sir LarsTech, Can I ask another question? How could I make that excess tab strip/empty space be the same color as my form color?

Comment: @rjtubera Probably best to search StackOverflow for that.  I think tab controls like to paint with system colors.  If you don't find the answer, try posting another question.

Answer (score 1):

Make another control, that has your table control at the top and the calendar at the bottom, put that on your main form.

Comment: looks like you've already done something, and my solution was more complicated. Google for .net compound controls you'll see what I meant.